# zip folder without root folder info included

Tags: cmd.exe, zip

I have a zip.exe in my cmd shell.
I would like to zip a folder in any subfolder, but don't want the folder to be zipped also.

Sample. I have the following situation:

```
c:/mainfolder/projectfolder/file.txt
c:/batch/zip.exe
```

The content of the resulting zip should be

```
projectfolder
projectfolder/file.txt
```

I would like to zip projectfolder, so the content of the zip file has only 
projectfolder with its file.txt. Mainfolder should not be visible.
I also would like to do this as a oneliner.

My attempt did not work:

```
c:/batch/zip.exe -FSJr c:/mainfolder/projectfolder.zip c:/mainfolder/projectfolder
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder will be zipped if it is specified, so the trick is not to specify it.

Do something similar to:

```
cd c:/mainfolder/
c:/batch/zip.exe -FSJr c:/mainfolder/projectfolder.zip *
```

Comment: Thanks. I see. It seems not be possible in a oneliner. Thanks you.

Comment: Still creates the parent folder when extracting. `A` & `B` files are within the `P` folder. Zipped `P` with this command but when extracting the `P.zip` -> `P/A,B`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Change your current work directory to the source directory.
`cd c:\mainfolder\`
`zip -FSJr c:/mainfolder/projectfolder.zip *`

p.s.: You could copy zip.exe to c:\windows this way you don't need to specify the fullpath to zip cmd. the `.exe` extension is not neccessary to write.

---

Do not use the `-r` switch

```
-r    Travel the directory structure recursively
```

Just use `zip.exe -FSJ c:/mainfolder/projectfolder.zip c:/mainfolder/projectfolder`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. That doesn't help me, because I want to go recursivly through the projectfolder. The content of the zip should have the projectfolder and the file in it. I only do not want the mainfolder too.